# I want to know the operating principles

Tags: c++

I think it should be inputted and output immediately, so why is it output at once after receiving all the input?
What's the principle of motion? Does it work like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    int num2;
    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> num2;
        cout << num2 << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input
5
1 2 3 4 5

Output
1
2
3
4
5

p.s. Happy new year!

Comment: It's not output at once after receiving all the input. After the first input which determines the number of iterations in the loop, each number is printed immediately after you input it.

Comment: From the way you present input and output I assume that the input is no t interactive and instead comes from reading non-interactive input. In that situation the output is exaclty as I expect it (and as Valentino explained it). Please explain in detail what output you would expect exactly and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird fact about `std::cin`, when you give multiple inputs, it uses all of them separately in their next occurrences as it exactly happened this time:

```
1 2 3 4 5 // stdin user input
```

In the first iteration, value 1 was used, in the second, 2 then 3 and so on. Watch this animation to understand it better:

[image: Demonstration using GDB debugger]

The best possible way is to provide those values line-by-line instead of putting them together.